# Delta Gamma Hedging Portfolio of Multiple Options Derivation

Tags: hedging, itos-lemma, delta-hedging, gamma, derivation

I am trying to make the correct derivation of the Delta Gamma Hedge of a portfolio composed of a multi-option strategy, like a Straddle with the following parameters Long 1 Call K = 100, Long 1 Put K = 100. So for this type of hedge, I am trying to reach to a result that tells me x number of options (for example a Put option P) to buy (to hedge Gamma) and y units of stock (to hedge Delta).

I understand the concept and derivation of x and y for a simple portfolio composed of 1 Long Call, for example, `π = C - xP - yS` which I would then need to differentiate to reach to:

```
dπ = dC - xdP - ydS

0 = Δds + 1/2 * Γ(ds)^2 - x(Δpds + 1/2 * ΓP(ds)^2) - yds

0 = Δds - xΔPds - yds + 1/2 * Γ(ds)^2) - x(1/2)*ΓP(ds)^2

0 = ds(Δ - xΔP - y) + (ds)^2 * [1/2 * (Γ - xΓP)

Δ - xΔP - y = 0, Γ - xΓP = 0
```

and eventually

```
x = Γ / ΓP  and  y = Δ - (Γ / ΓP) * ΔP
```

What I am not understanding is how do I reach x and y when I have a portfolio composed of several options, for example a Straddle as I mentioned, which would make the following portfolio:

```
π = C + P - xP - yS
```

how would I proceed ? Because if I differentiate this portfolio equation wouldn't the equation just be

```
dπ = dC + dP - xdP - ydS --> Δds + 1/2 * Γ(ds)^2 + Δds + 1/2 * Γ(ds)^2 - x(Δpds + 1/2 * ΓP(ds)^2) - yds
```

Would I still reach the same expression for `x = Γ / ΓP  and  y = Δ - (Γ / ΓP) * ΔP` even though the calculations would be a bit more complicated. Is there something I'm missing ? Any info / resources are appreciated as I'm also trying to learn how to calculate Delta Gamma Hedging, x and y, for more complicated strategies like a Butterfly Spread.

Comment: It's just the sum of individual Greeks.